# Fb.Connect not defined error while implementing FB logout

Tags: php, javascript, django, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to implement a facebook logout functionality for my django app. Facebook login works just fine for me. Now i need to logout and clear the sessions somehow. FOr that i was trying to do with the code below, but its throwing 'FB.Connect not defined ' error. Can somebody pleas look at my code and give me a solution ?

```
    <html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
     <div id="fb-root"></div>
     <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
     <script>
       FB.init({
         appId  : 'xxx',
         status : true, // check login status
         cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
         xfbml  : true  // parse XFBML
       });
     </script>
        <script>
            function logout(){
            FB.logout(function(response) {
  // user is now logged out
  location.href = '/user_sessions/new';
});}

            // handle a session response from any of the auth related calls
            function handleFBSessionResponse(response) {
                /*
                //Check the facebook login status
                alert("handleFBSessionResponse(), "
                 + "\nresponse.status="+response.status
                 +" \nresponse.session="+response.session
                 +" \nresponse.perms="+response.perms);
                */

                //if we do have a non-null response.session, call FB.logout(),
                //the JS method will log the user out
                //of Facebook and remove any authorization cookies
                FB.logout(handleFBSessionResponse);
            }


            </script>
            <a href="javascript:logout();">Logout</a >
```

Or is there any other straight forward easy way to implement it, if so please post that code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got it working with this

```
<a href="http://m.facebook.com/logout.php?confirm=1&next=http://10.1.0.90:8080/registrationForm" >Sign Out</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
FB.logout(handleFBSessionResponse);
```

It seems weird that you are passing the callback function inside itself. Try to do something like that instead:

```
FB.logout(function(response) {
  // user is now logged out
  location.href = '/user_sessions/new';
});
```

And remove the other location.href reference in your code.

Comment: it gave me this error "FB.logout is not a function" ;should i remove the method 'function handleFBSessionResponse(response) ' ?

Comment: i have changed the code..now the control is not going inside Fb.connect.logout()..is it the right way to call ?